# JavaScript: How do I access the prototype of an object inside another object?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

So I think I'm going crazy here. I'm trying to use prototype in my code, so I will have a Layer object that will have a Figure Object that will have a _newFigure function.

```
Layer = function(){}
Layer.prototype.figure = function(){}
Layer.prototype.figure.prototype._newFigure = function(){
    //(Creates new Figure)
}
```

What I'm expecting in pseudo-code:

```
[LayerObject]{
    figure:{
        _newFigure:function(){
            //(Creates new Figure)
        }    
    }
}
```

Now that, **to me**, would be the logical thing to do, but for some reason it doens't work.
Do you now how can I achieve that? Keep in mind I'm using prototype for performance reasons.

-- *thanks in advance* --

**UPDATE---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------**

As **Nick** said *"Why does Layer need to have a Figure on it's prototype? It seems like Layer and Figure our separate entities, and a Layer can have a Figure instance attached to it. Just a thought : )"*

So, I've updated the code (now working)

```
Layer = function(){
    this.figure = new figureHandler(this);
}

function figureHandler(layer){
    this.layer = layer;
}

figureHandler.prototype._newFigure = function(){
    //(Creates new Figure)
}
```

-- *See ya! Thanks for your help :)* --

Comment: Why does Layer need to have a Figure on it's prototype? It seems like Layer and Figure our separate entities, and a Layer can have a Figure instance attached to it. Just a thought : )

Comment: You don't want to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Would something like the following work for you?

```
Figure = function() {};
Layer = function() {}; 
Layer.prototype.figure = function() {
  return new Figure();
};
```

It's a bit confusing to me why you would want an interface like `layer.figure._newFigure` when `layer.figure` could create a new figure object for you. Perhaps your use case just isn't clear enough to me.

**EDIT:** Based on the comment to my original response, I assume you mean something like this:

```
Figure = function(layer) {
  this.layer = layer;
};
Layer = function() {};
Layer.prototype.figure = function() {
  return new Figure(this);
};
```

Comment: Figure needs a Layer so you could pass `this` to Figure constructor so Figure can set it's layer. You could wrap the argument in an object so if inheritance is needed or it's called as part of a long function chain you can pass the arg object along without changing the function signature.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for something like this:

Figure has a Layer instance and a Layer instance has multiple figures. Layer may have a factory that will create Figures having the current Layer instance:

```
Layer = function Layer(){
  this.figures = [];
};
Layer.prototype.addFigure = function addFigure(arg){
  arg = arg || {};
  arg.layer = this;
  this.figures.push(new Figure(arg));
  return this;//now you can stack functions
}
Figure = function Figure(arg){
  arg = arg || {};
  //layer is not optional
  this.layer = arg.layer 
    || (function(){
      throw new Error('Cannot create figure without layer');
    }());
  this.shape = arg.shape || 'square';
}
var l = new Layer();
l.addFigure({shape:'round'})//stacking next addFigure on next line
  .addFigure();//defaults to square
console.log(l.figures);
```

More info on constructor functions and prototype here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941